# 403 error on wordpress install, but site still working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cpanel, http-status-code-403

I'm getting a '403 Forbidden' error on a website, even though the site is still viewable..

The cPanel error console is filling up with;
"Directory index forbidden by Options directive" 
I'm unsure whether this is related..

The htaccess file;

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>


# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

I've tried deactivating all the plugins, this did not resolve the issue. 
I'm notsure where else to look..

Thanks

Comment: Just to eliminate the possibility: the syntax highlighting above is a little strange.  Can you confirm the quotes at the end of `ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”` are right (same for your css)?  They don't match the opening quotes.  More generally - if you take everything out of your `.htaccess` except the WordPress directives, does the problem go away?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, the quotations have been fixed and htaccess file tested (with and with out mod_expires.c and DEFLATE info ). i can confirm its still showing the 403 error. Could this be a problem caused by a mis-configuration , at system admin level? with the hosting company.

Comment: Not sure (never seen it), but it seems it could be.  According to [the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) `Options FollowSymLinks` must be enabled for `RewriteRule`s to work.  From [this thread](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/69346-solved-mod-rewritehtaccess-403-error/), it seems to throw a 403 if it's not.  Might be worth checking.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggest Hobo, gave it ago. But still getting the 403. Thats the strange thing tho, i believe RewriteRule is working otherwise the site wouldn't be viewable from the the root dir. http://syrp.co.nz

Comment: Dunno - would've thought if you're in the root directory you'd pick up `index.php` by default (assuming Apache's `DirectoryIndex` directive is fairly standard), so wouldn't need the `RewriteRule` working. Though that doesn't really help solve the problem.  Sorry - out of ideas if `Options FollowSymLinks` doesn't work.